# Save multiple variables from bash script to text file

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script I have written to count the number of lines in a collection of text files, and I store each number of lines as a variable using a for loop. I would like to print each variable to the same text file, so that I may access all the line counts at once, from the same file.

My code is:

```
for f in *Daily.txt; do
    lines=$(cat $f | wc -l);
    lines=$(($num_lines -1));
    echo $lines > /destdrive/linesTally2014.txt;
done
```

When I run this, the only output I receive is of the final file, not all the other files.

If anyone could help me with this I would really appreciate it. I am new to bash scripting, so please excuse this novice question.

Comment: Is `lines=$(cat ...)` a typo for `num_lines=$(cat ...)`?

Comment: `lines=$(( $(wc -l < "$f") - 1))` would be the proper way to get that value in one line.

Comment: @chepner: I think it is more a question that `lines=$(($num_lines - 1))` is a typo for `lines=$(($lines - 1))`.  But there is a problem with name consistency.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the file on each iteration.  Move the I/O redirection after the `done`.  Use:

```
for f in *Daily.txt
do
    echo $(( $(wc -l < $f) - 1))
done > /destdrive/linesTally2014.txt
```

This avoids the variable; if you have a need for it, you can use a fixed version of the original code (use `$lines` throughout, instead of using `$num_lines` once).  Note that the code in the question has a UUoC (Useless Use of `cat`) that this version avoids.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the loop with

```
wc -l *Daily.txt | awk '{ print $1 }' > /destdrive/linesTally2014.txt
```

or (when you want 1 less)

```
wc -l *Daily.txt | awk '{ print $1 -1 }' > /destdrive/linesTally2014.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The above suggestions are probably better, but the problem you're having with *your* script is your use of the `>` for redirection, which overwrites the file. Use `>>` and it will append to the file.

```
echo $lines >> /destdrive/linesTally2014.txt
```

Comment: No problem and welcome to SO; if you found any of the answers useful, upvote them, and mark the most helpful one as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark.